# perplexed by UIWebView in a single view application

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

I can do this in a tabbed application, no problem, but getting it to work in a single-view application (using xib) is driving me crazy.

I've created a new class, WebViewController.  The header is:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "GHViewController.h"

@interface GHWebViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *webView;

@end
```

And the implementation is:

```
#import "GHWebViewController.h"

@implementation GHWebViewController

@synthesize webView = _webView;

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *fullURL=@"http://www.amazon.com/Books-by-Joel-Derfner/lm/RVZNXKV59PL51/ref=cm_lm_byauthor_full";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}

@end
```

So far, so good.  But going to the web view is only one option of several available to the user (through bar buttons).  So I've added a `UIWebView` to my `ViewController` but hidden it until the user presses the button to go to the web view.

And here's where I'm stuck.  I've tried making this a delegate of that, and that a delegate of the other thing, and I can't tell what's right and what's wrong, and the `IBOutlet` in `WebViewController` won't connect to anything in my `ViewController` and I'm just getting more and more confused.  I tried adding another xib for `WebViewController` but that just led to disaster.  I'm out of my depth here.

So my multi-part question is:

1. Is using a `UIWebView` as one of several options as I've described possible with a single-view application?
2. If so, what do I need to do to accomplish it--thinking of a) delegation, b) code, and c) connections in the User Interface?
3. If not, how should I approach the task instead?

Off to see Total Recall.  Perhaps that'll clear my head....

Comment: From your description, a set of bar buttons that will choose between alternate views, it does sound like a tab view controller is exactly what you need, or to look at it another way you are sort of reinventing it. Why did you decide to move away from it?

Comment: This is silly, but . . . I like the gray bar at the bottom better than the black bar.

Comment: (And the way the buttons look, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if I fully understand your question; the paragraph before your 3 questions are somewhat confusing...

But some thoughts:

1. You don't need that ivar in interface. Esp. you shouldn't have `IBOutlet` in your ivar declaration. If you need `IBOutlet`, it should be in your `@property` declaration rather than your ivar.
2. Maybe you don't really need an `IBOutlet`. i.e. you don't need to put your webView on xib. (you can if you want to, but you don't need to.)
3. So you can just have an `IBAction` hooked up with a button. When that button is clicked, you can `alloc init` your webView (and set its frame), add it to your `self.view`, and set `webview.delegate = self` or something.
4. Then you can handle the `loadURL` and stuff like normal. When you click on that button again (or some other button), you just remove your webview from your view.

Comment: And that totally took care of it!  Thank you!